# What to do before reformatting phone or setting back to factory state?

Tags: factory-reset, reformat

Recently it seems as if my phone has bogged down to a point where is is almost unusable (Droid Eris running 2.1).

I'm on the verge of reformatting or setting back to a factory state. I was wondering what things should I do to make sure I have all my contacts/pics/etc.. and what tools can help me accomplish this?  Also what about the apps I have paid for?  How can I get those to transfer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you have an SD card, I would copy its contents to a PC.  That should save all of your pictures.
2. Paid apps are linked to your Google account and can always be re-downloaded.
3. Have you entered your contacts manually and not synced them to your Google account?  If not, you don't need to back them up; they're in the "cloud", to use the common catchphrase.
4. If you're rooted, you can use an app like [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to save your applications and data, so that you don't need to redownload them (and so your settings, saved games, etc. are backed up).

Answer (score 5):

Your contacts and calendar will be stored in the cloud and synced back when you re-login with the same Google Account. Also, most of your settings. Apps that you purchased will be listed in your Market Account.

I suggest you use SMS Backup or something similar to save your messages (if you wish to) to your Storage Card. GoSMS and Handcent SMS also have SMS backup/restore facility.

By default, your camera pics are stored in the DCIM folder on your storage card.

Use a backup app like Titanium Backup or MyBackup Pro to backup all the stuff first, just as an additional safety net.

NOTE: Busy right now, so haven't added links. A quick search will turn up the apps in the Market. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing all these steps regardless of the fact that your data is in the cloud

1. Download MyBackUp Pro (or a similar app)
2. Backup everything to a micro SD card
3. Deactivate any license (for BlockBuster Movies, etc)
4. Export anything that is exportable (like contacts, calendars, pictures, etc)

I always say that its better to be super safe than sorry. Sometimes if you have multiple accounts that merge data into one place, you may expect Tom Smith (example use of name) to be on Google's servers but they are actually on FaceBook or some other server. By exporting it, you'll have a file with everyone and then you can upload the contacts to your Gmail account.

I say this from personal experience by losing pictures and data.